# delete all elements from objectlist except one selected element

Tags: delphi

What is best coding practise in deleting all elements from a list except one element which I would like to keep inside the list?

```
TMyCLass = Class()
     ....
end;


MyObjectList = TObjectList <TMyClass>;


var MySaveClass : TMyCLass;
begin
    MySaveClass = MyObjectList.items[saveindex];

    for i = 1... MyObjectList.count-1 do
       if i <> saveindex then 
       MyObjectList.delete (i); ??  //  not working  :-) 

end;
```

Comment: [`Extract`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Extract) the item. Then [`Clear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Clear) the list, [`Add`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Add) the item back to the list. [`DeleteRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.DeleteRange) looks to me wasteful here.

Comment: @TLama: Why do you keep misusing comments to give answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TLama said in a comment, [Extract](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Extract) the item, [Clear](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Clear) the list (if OwnsObjects is false, loop through and free each item first), and then [Add](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Add) the item back in.

```
var
  SavedItem: TMyClass;
...
  SavedItem := MyObjectList.Extract(MyObjectList.Items[i]);
  // Loop here to free if needed because list doesn't own objects
  MyObjectList.Clear;
  MyObjectList.Add(SavedItem);
```

Comment: If OwnsObjects is FALSE then rather than iterating and freeing each item, you can set it to TRUE, then CLEAR, then set it back to FALSE.

Comment: @Dsm If OwnsObjects is false, then presumably something else owns them and you should not be destroying them

Comment: @David Hefferman - presumubly true of the original solution also? I merely made a comment to make the solution easier. And I believe the comment to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

If the Objectlist has OwnsObjects := True then you can just delete the elements.
But care to make it backwards otherwise you might get an error.

```
for i := MyObjectlist.count -1 downto 0 do
  if i = Saveindex then
    continue
  else
    MyObjectList.Delete(i);
```

Comment: if i = Saveindex I do not want to delete this object,  therefore delete with i < Seveindex will not work

Comment: well than try  if MyObjectlist[i] = MyObjectList[SaveIndex] then continue;  But I think the approach that Ken White & TLama suggest is more reasonable than iterating, i just wanted to point out that you should iterate backwards instead of forwards to avoid mistakes. Cheers.

Comment: Did you try running this code, with 10 items in the list and SaveItem = 8?